# Can I use stock kernel with xorg edgers PPA?

Tags: kernel

Good evening everyone, my question, basically, is in the title. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit with Intel+Nvidia card Bumblebee installed. Reason for this question is, I noticed, that on stock kernel my battery life is a lot higher than in kernel (which is 3.7 in xorg edgers ppa). But in the ppa it is listed that

> This PPA is currently meant to be used as a whole. Please do *not*
>   individually install packages from it, add it to your sources and let
>   your package manager pull in every update.

so my question is can I use stick 3.5 kernel with this PPA enabled and all updates installed from it or I should use kernel from this PPA?

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the 3.5 kernel is the current standard for 12.10[[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232625/nvidia-driver-installation-error#comment287572_232625).
So unless you need the Xorg-edgers ppa, you should be able to just either:

- Completely uninstall the kernel and all its extra things (using synaptic, terminal, etc.)
- Remove the PPA

or

- Have your computer auto-boot into the 3.5 kernel, by using [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) to set grub to always boot into the previously booted kernel.

However, this second option forces you to manually switch to the new kernel if there is an update (by selecting the new kernel in grub), since it will keep using the previous kernel.