# Nvidia drivers installed, but not used

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04

I have an Asus UL30JT. It has Nvidia Optimus technology which I am not really interested in.
I currently rarely use this laptop with it being connected to power. And I want to be able to play video at high res, play games and do some OpenCL coding.

In the BIOS I switched it to NVIDIA only (non windows 7).
Previously, this worked just fine, using the nvidia driver.

After upgrading everything was broken. I have added nomodeset and blacklist.nouveau=1 as kernel options.
The nvidia drivers install without error. However they are not found/used.

```
jockey-text -l
kmod:nvidia_310_updates - nvidia_310_updates (Proprietary, Enabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_304_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_313_updates - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_310 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
kmod:nvidia_304 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
```

Trying to load the module manually fails as well.

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
```

Xorg.0.log show the following:

```
[    12.028] Loading extension GLX
[    12.028] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.037] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    12.037] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.037] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    12.037] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    12.037] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    12.037] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    12.037] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    12.037] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    12.038] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    12.038] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    12.038] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.038] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    12.038] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.038] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    12.038] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    12.038] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    12.039] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
```

I have installed the kernel headers, of the correct kernel.
I verified that the kernel options are in the grub configuration.
I have purged all nvidia packages and tried to reinstall (multiple times...)

Currently I am at a loss.
I have checked the following question:
[Nvidia driver installation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232625/nvidia-driver-installation-error)
But nothing there worked for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, I found out of it.

I did a full `apt-get purge nvidia*` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` etc. But the thing that fixed it was actually to set the alternative correct. I guess this would've worked from the start. So here's how:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia-310/ld.so.conf              9702      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/nvidia-310/ld.so.conf              9702      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf   500       manual mode
```

As you see, for me, this setting was wrongly set. So I used `0` instead, and lo' and behold. Lots more nvidia- utilities in the PATH.

If you're not on 64-bit, then use i386 instead of x86_64.

Comment: `purge nvidia*` and re-`install`-ing `nvidia-current` fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't this be `apt-get purge "nvidia*"`

Answer (score 10):

Install latest nvidia drivers

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates`

Generate `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` by executing

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Then execute

`sudo software-properties-gtk` which will show you a window like this

[image]

Select the latest driver from that list and then do

`sudo reboot`

Comment: This fails at the second step for me (sudo nvidia-xconfig) sudo: nvidia-xconfig: command not found

Comment: Sorry. Included steps to install nvidia-xconfig

Comment: E: Unable to locate package nvidia-xconfig

Comment: No worries. Please skip the nvidia-xconfig step.

Comment: Did all of the above in one session (excluding the xconfig step), no avail. Still can't load the nvidia module.

Comment: Were you able to see nvidia-313 in the Additional Drivers list?

Comment: yes, I can see nvidia-313-updates (proprietary) in the list

Comment: Then, nvidia-xconfig is the problem. Let me check how I installed it.

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings` and then run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Comment: nvidia-settings-313-updates is already the newest version. Apparently there is a specific settings utility for each driver version

Comment: Then this must be fixing it. Whatever we installed are just updates. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-310` This must be installing nvidia-xconfig along with it.

Comment: that also didn't work. In the end I was so fed up with it that I reinstalled...

Comment: This is so strange. I did find the nvidia-xconfig, it was just not installed to my PATH but in /usr/lib/nvidia-304/bin/, ran from there. But then Xorg couldn't find nvidia_drv.so because it was also not linked up. So something is seriously wrong with the post_install script.

Comment: Works for me (all steps). 
My setup ubuntu 14.04 64bit; on a Lenovo W530 
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M]

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that end up in this thread when shooting in the Google dark because nvidia drivers are loaded, but all graphics in X go through the CPU instead of the GPU.

### Symptoms

- nvidia drivers were loaded correctly (`lsmod | grep nvidia`)
- under X, `nvidia-settings` was reporting no issues accessing my GTX 680 GPU

BUT

- any graphics-intensive program would drive **C**PU load unusually high, instead of the expected load on the **G**PU. For example, games would stutter even at an animated main menu, `glxgears` (from the `mesa-utils` package) would load the CPU up to 10%, `unigine` load test would show FPS around 2 and lock up on first scene.

The misleading factor was that `nvidia-settings` was not reporting any problems accessing the GPU. I did what most threads suggested (purged and reinstalled nvidia drivers), but to no effect. In desperation I finally checked `Xorg.0.log` in `/var/log`: it turned out that X was loading it's own `libglx.so` module instead of nvidia's. Now that I was asking the right question, I got the proper answer ([Xorg loads wrong libglx.so](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1276123)).

### Solution

Originally the `Files` section in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` was empty:

```
Section "Files"
EndSection
```

I found where nvidia keeps its own `libglx.so` (more precisely, I found where it keeps  a symlink to it). The solution is to tell X to first look for modules in nvidia's path, and then in Xorg's path, so the `Files` section now looks like this:

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection
```

I'm on Debian, but as Ubuntu is based on Debian, a similar approach should work on Ubuntu systems.

Comment: thank you, I was already banging my head against the desk with nvidia-legacy-390xx

Comment: It worked for me as well, but the path was /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg instead of /usr/lib/nvidia (2 monitors setup, nvidia 2060 RTX Super, driver 470). I had this issue with module loading in 430, then in 440 and 450 drivers it disappeared, and then in 460 and 470 reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced problem with nvidia module not found after update too. Just black screen - no grafics at all. 
I have tried different commands, so maybe I miss some important actions, but I provided that sequence, and it helps:

boot Ubuntu recovery, root shell

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mountall
<log in as user>
sudo  apt-get remove nvidia-340 nvidia-340-updates
```

then reboot the computer. I have already installed nvidia-331 &Co installed.