# games unplayable, staticy. ubuntu 14.04

Tags: games

When i try to play XCOM: Enemy unknown, this happens

[image: Xcom screenshot]

and as well with DotA 2. Steam version, reinstalled twice on both.

[image: DotA 2]

Comment: Are there multiple drivers available on your system? Did you try a different video driver? Is your system up to date? Can you check `/var/logs/Xorg.0.log` for any errors (with (EE) in front of the lines)? Also, is this the native Steam client or the Windows one using Wine?

Comment: Ah, I knew I was forgetting something!
 Trying that now.

Comment: Failed to load module "Nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Settings manager
 -Additional Drivers
   -chose latest nvidia or novue driver
System
     -Nvidia Xserver Settings
       -Check resolutions
       -Check GPU thermostat
       -make sure no other onboard gfx processors are running

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OP of [this thread at the nvidia dev forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/734584/nvidia-driver-is-unable-to-load/) had a similar issue, which lead me to [this thread on AskUbuntu!](https://askubuntu.com/q/289459/335497) with two (similar) solutions.