# Ubuntu doesn't discover graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

My graphics card is GT 710. I've installed it, physically, correctly. However `lspci -v` doesn't show Nvidia graphics card anywhere. Here is the output (only entries since details are ommited due to length):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])  
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
```

I also tried `lspci | grep 3D` and it returns nothing.

`lspci | grep VGA` only shows `Intel Corporation 4 Series ...`, which is the default onboard graphics:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

Though, I went on and tried installing drivers. I followed the instructions in [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers), installing nvidia-381, which is the lastest driver. After installing I opened `Nvidia X Server Settings` but there was no `PRIME profiles`, despite `nvidia-prime` being installed automatically alongside `nvidia-381` and `bumblebee` removed.

`sudo nvidia-xconfig` returned this:

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

I tried re-installing `xorg` and `openbox` but nothing changed.

I searched for problems of installed drivers and tried this [Nvidia drivers installed, but not used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289459/nvidia-drivers-installed-but-not-used#308504). I executed `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf`:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf (providing /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia-381/ld.so.conf              8604      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/nvidia-381-prime/ld.so.conf        8603      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-381/ld.so.conf              8604      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf   500       manual mode
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

changed choice to `0`, which is `/usr/lib/nvidia-381/ld.so.conf`. However after reboot the choice was back to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf` again. I think there are many problems but these can be traced to the fact that Ubuntu doesn't detect the graphics card.

If you have any idea I would really appreciate.

Edit: Here is the full result of `lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1230 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:03.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4 Series Chipset HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f052a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:03.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PT IDER Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4 Series Chipset PT IDER Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 1238 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 1260 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1240 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 1264 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1220 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_generic
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi

00:03.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Serial KT Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4 Series Chipset Serial KT Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 1248 [size=8]
    Memory at f0524000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: serial

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f0500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f0525000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 1100 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at 1120 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at 1140 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    I/O ports at 1160 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at f0527000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at f0520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=20, subordinate=20, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: f8000000-f81fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f8200000-00000000f83fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=30, subordinate=30, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: f8400000-f85fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f8600000-00000000f87fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at 1180 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at 11a0 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    I/O ports at 11c0 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at f0528000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JDO (ICH10DO) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JDO (ICH10DO) LPC Interface Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    I/O ports at 1250 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 1268 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1258 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 126c [size=4]
    I/O ports at 11e0 [size=32]
    Memory at f0526000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci`. If it is not shown there, then there is no Nvidia adapter, or it is disabled in BIOS. You can't fix it by installing drivers.

Comment: Maybe you installed the card badly, or did not connect power to it, etc.

Comment: @Pilot6 I installed it correctly. The fan works, everything is in place. The card doesn't need additional power supply (it's only 23 watts). I Checked the BIOS, in `PCI Settings`, the `VGA controller` has 4 options `IRQ0, IRQ5, IRQ10, IRQ11`. I don't know what those are or should I change the value

Comment: The `VGA Controller` is actually `Intel VGA Controller`. There's also `Disable option`. I tried it. doesn't work.

Comment: This output means that the PCI bus does not see the Nvidia. It is not related to Ubuntu or any drivers.